# Prove two matrices are similar (Frobenius normal form related)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $x^2+a_1x+a_0\in\mathbb{R}[x]$, irreducible polynomial.  It's roots are $\alpha \pm \beta i$. Show that $A=\left( {\matrix{
>    0 & { - {a_0}}  \cr 
>    1 & { - {a_1}}  \cr 
>  } } \right)$ is similar to  $B= \left( {\matrix{
>    \alpha & {  \beta}  \cr 
>    -\beta & {  \alpha}  \cr 
>  } } \right)$

I was guided to find an eigen vector of this matrix. So I looked at $\ker(B-(\alpha+i\beta)I_2)$ and found it's basis is $\left\{ (-i,1) \right\}$.

So we can take $v = -i +1$ as an eigen-vector. Now I was told to look at the real part and the imaginary part and figure out something, but I don't see how is it gonna help here.

Comment: Are you implying $a_1=-1$?

Comment: But if $\;a_{21}=1\;$ then $\;\det A=a_0=(\alpha+\beta\,i)(\alpha-\beta\,i)=\alpha^2+\beta^2\;$ , and $\;\det B=\alpha^2\color{red}-\beta^2\;$ . Perhaps one of the those two $\;-\beta\;$ in $\;B\;$ should be $\;+\beta\;$ ?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've edited the typo.

Comment: $A$ is in the form of a companion matrix.

Comment: Yes, I know that's the companion matrix of that quadratic polynomial, yet $\;B\;$ cannot be similar to $\;A\;$ , even after the change of $\;a_{21}\;$, because of the reason I wrote in my above comment. Perhaps I'm making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Oh you right. Sorry for those typos guys..

Comment: But then there's no question already: both the characteristic and the minimal polynomials of both matrices are the same same, and this is enough to have them similar as they're $\;2\times 2\;$ matrices. You could also use the Jordan Form.

Comment: Is it true only for $2\times 2$ matrices?

Comment: @AmitBB Also for $\;3\times 3\;$ matrices. For higher orders this isn't already enough.

Comment: I wish to understand how the hint given to me should help with solving this problem. I should form a basis (If not mistaken) from the coefficients of the chosen eigen-vector.

Comment: @AmitBB So showing the char. and minimal polynomials are the same will not solve it for you?

Comment: It's a great solution actually, but I think I should follow the hint of the exercise.